# React Native: upgrading to v0.16.0 errors (android)

Tags: android, react-native

When I try to upgrade to React Native version 0.16.0, I can't get past the errors.

The issue is that it doesn't seem to finish "fetching js bundle" in the emulator (using Genymotion). And then after a while, the red screen error comes up: `undefined is not an object (evaluating 'require('NativeModules').UIManager.AndroidSwipeRefreshLayout.Constants')`

If I try Chrome debugging, I get a red error screen with `Cannot read property 'Constants' of undefined`

And if Dev mode is true/checked (no longer debugging in Chrome), I get a different error: `TypeError: expected dynamic type 'double', but had type 'boolean' (constructing arguments for RTCNetworking.sendRequest at argument index 5)`

These errors seem to be coming from the react-native node module.  I'm not really sure how to fix this or if it's something really obvious.

Also, I'd like to note that with v0.15.0, in android/app/build.gradle, only this worked: `compile "com.facebook.react:react-native:0.14.+"`.  Would that need to change for v0.16.0?  I have tried changing it, but without success, unless it's a completely different number.

Answer (score 0):

So I'm not totally sure what the issue was, but it was suggested that some part of my project was corrupted.  So I fixed the issue by creating a new project from scratch and replacing the android/ and ios/ folders and contents in my project with the newly initialized one and making sure to switch out the project name in all the files. I also checked .flowconfig and that had changed as well, so I gave it the newer version.

I then `npm install`ed (after I changed to v0.16.0 in package.json) and made a build on the emulator with `react-native run-android`.

So again, not sure what the exact problem was, but it does seem to be working now.

Answer (score 0):

It's an issue with the 0.16.0 release. See: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/4568. Upgrading to 0.16.1 should fix it.